How to turn off shadows and reflections?
How to turn off white shadows on an objects like in the attached image?

I'd like the blender to display simplest, purest view possible to fit some textures on meshes. I absolutely don't need any lights, shadows, reflections etc. Just an uniform sun like light to evenly light up the scene.

Have you tried to lower down the Specular value? Or use an Emission shader instead of a Principled BSDF?

Light Path Node:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/light_path.html

If you just want to show the raw coloring without any refractions, shadows etc. there are two easy and quick ways that come to my mind right now. First, just plug your color value, which goes into the principled bsdf right into the material output, just like in the image:

The second one is to simply enable to only show the raw Color Diffuse. To set this up, go the Shading dropdown menu left of the Viewport shading settings and change the "Renderpass" setting to "Diffuse Color.
Again, like in the Image:

I hope this helps :)
